# How to pass multiple arguments in a cleaner way in python

Tags: python, coding-style

I have the following code that I wanted to know if there is a cleaner version to do the following. The function basically accepts some data dict and parses it, manipulates it, constructs another dictionary, and finally sends some initial data values along with constructed dict to another function to store in db.

Can anyone help me put this structure in a better way?

```
def process_metadata(data):

    # extract data fields 

    # here result constructs another metadata from some of the above values

    result = {
                            "identifier": _id,
                            "type": ["t1", "t2", "t3", t4],
                            "properties": {
                                "p1": v1,
                                "p2": v2,
                                "p3": v3,
                                "p4": v4,
                                "p5": v5,
                                "p6": v6,
                                "p7": v7,
                                "p8": v8,
                                "p9": "v9",
                                "p10": v10,
                                "p11": v11,
                                "p12": v12,
                                "p13": v13,
                                "p14": v14,
                                "p15": v15,
                                "p16": v16,
                                "p17": v17,
                                "p18": v18,
                                "p19": "v19",
                                "p20": v20,
                                "p21": v21,
                                "p22": "v22",
                                "p23": "v23",
                                "p24": v24,
                                "p25": v25,
                                "p26": v26,
                                "p27": v27,
                                "p28": v28,
                                "p29": v29,
                                "p30": v30,
                                "p31": v31,
                                "p32": v32,
                                "p33": v33,
                                "p34": v34,
                                "p35": v35,
                                "p36": "v36",
                                "p37": v37
                            }
                        }
    return another_function(data, result)
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass them in as keyword arguments to a function?  You can always do **data to unpack the dictionary into keyword-argument pairs.  Otherwise I'm not sure how much 'cleaner' you can make just passing in the dictionary as a single argument, I do this as well for dictionaries of data.

Comment: @Atihska for properties use loop  in `range(1,37,1)` of variables

Comment: What don't you like about it? there are a lot of keys/attributes they will need to be *defined* somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make properties a class with constructor taking in v1-v37 and store the instantiated properties object in result, then your result will have three fields and you access your properties via `result["properties"].v32`